# SFTP Connector Configuration

Tags: java, mule, sftp

I have a requirement to send a file to an external vendor using SFTP. For that we will have to download a client certificate and a key. We are using Mule EE 3.6.2 Is it possible to configure a SSL Client in SFTP Outbound as we do with http  utilizing the SFTP connector. I couldn't find anything in the SFTP connector documentation. Thanks.

Regards,
Hari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the SFTP connector with an `identityFile` and it's associated `passphrase`

```
<sftp:endpoint name="get-file"  host="${sftp.host}" port="${sftp.port}" path="${sftp.path}"
        user="${sftp.username}" responseTimeout="10000" pollingFrequency="${sftp.pollInterval}"
        identityFile="${app.home}/${sftp.keyPath}" passphrase="${sftp.passphrase}" connector-ref="sftp">
    </sftp:endpoint>
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan I will give it a shot and let you know.